# SQL Server - Função para formatar campo de data com comando convert

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte função:

`select convert(DATE,GETDATE(),101)`

Onde ela me retorna da seguinte forma: `2021-08-17`

Quero que ele me retorne um dado com este formato `"17/8/2021"` mantendo o dado como `date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando utiliza a função `convert`, está usando um estilo de exibição da data. O recomendado é utilizar `varchar` nessa situação para fazer a apresentação da informação. Para manipular o registro com o tipo `DATE`, deve manipular antes de fazer a conversão. Veja um exemplo:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = GETDATE();
Select convert(varchar, @d, 103) as hoje, convert(varchar, dateadd(day,1,@d), 103) as amanhã
```

**Resultado:**

| hoje | amanhã |
| --- | --- |
| 18/08/2021 | 19/08/2021 |

A função `convert()` é utilizada para exibição da informação. Veja que para calcular a data `amanhã`, primeiro foi utilizada a data com a forma original `date` na função `dateadd()` e depois o resultado foi convertido para a forma de exibição desejada com o `convert()`.

### Outra opção de exibir no formato dd/MM/yyyy:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT FORMAT( @d, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'pt-BR' ) AS 'Data'
```

**Resultado:**

| Data |
| --- |
| 18/08/2021 |

### Outras estilos de data:

```
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 1)' as 'Consulta', convert(varchar, getdate(), 1) as 'Resultado' union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 2)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 2) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 3)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 3) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 4)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 4) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 5)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 5) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 6)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 6) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 7)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 7) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 10)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 10) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 11)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 11) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 12)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 12) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 23)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 23) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 102)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 104)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 106)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 107)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) union
select 'convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)', convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
```

**Resultado:**

| Consulta | Resultado |
| --- | --- |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 1) | 08/18/21 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 10) | 08-18-21 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) | 08/18/2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) | 2021.08.18 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) | 18/08/2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) | 18.08.2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) | 18-08-2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) | 18 Ago 2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) | Ago 18, 2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 11) | 21/08/18 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) | 08-18-2021 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) | 2021/08/18 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) | 20210818 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 12) | 210818 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 2) | 21.08.18 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 23) | 2021-08-18 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 3) | 18/08/21 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 4) | 18.08.21 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 5) | 18-08-21 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 6) | 18 Ago 21 |
| convert(varchar, getdate(), 7) | Ago 18, 21 |

Leia mais sobre as funções `Convert`, `Cast` e `Format` para SqlServer em:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
2. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15